# Does a Netty client work with a netty server only?

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to develop a client to communicate with a biometric device using a custom protocol but nothing seems to work.
I'm using a MessageToByteEncoder and a MessageToByteDecoder to handle the input and output data:

```
public class PacketDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext context, ByteBuf input, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("readable bytes: " + input.readableBytes());
        if (input.readableBytes() >= 1) {
            if (input.getByte(0) != DataCodes.START_BYTE) {
                input.readByte();
                return;
            }
        }
        if (input.readableBytes() >= 3) {
            byte command = input.getByte(2);
            boolean extendedLenght = (command & 0x80) == 0x80;
            short dataLength;
            int headerLength;
            if (extendedLenght) {
                byte[] dataLengthBytes = new byte[2];
                input.getBytes(3, dataLengthBytes);
                dataLength = Utils.getShort(dataLengthBytes);
                headerLength = 5;
            } else {
                dataLength = input.getByte(3);
                headerLength = 4;
            }

            int totalLength = headerLength + dataLength + 16;
            if (input.readableBytes() >= totalLength) {
               byte[] packetBytes = input.readBytes(totalLength).array();
                Packet packet = PacketConverter.decode(packetBytes);
                System.out.println("packet decoded");
                out.add(packet);
            }
        }
    }
}


public class PacketEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Packet> {
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext context, Packet packet, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        byte[] packetBytes = PacketConverter.encode(packet);
        out.writeBytes(packetBytes);
    }
}
```

and the connnection class:

```
public class Connection implements PacketListener {
    private final byte deviceAddress;
    private ChannelFuture channelFuture;
    private EventLoopGroup workerGroup;
    private final Object readLock = new Object();
    private Packet responsePacket;

    public Connection(byte deviceAddress) {
        this.deviceAddress = deviceAddress;
    }

    public void connect(String address, int port) {
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup);
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(
                        new PacketEncoder(),
                        new PacketDecoder(),
                        new PacketHandler(Connection.this)
                );
            }
        });

        channelFuture = b.connect(address, port);
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        channelFuture.channel().disconnect().syncUninterruptibly();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }

    @Override
    public void receive(Packet packet) {
        synchronized (readLock) {
            this.responsePacket = packet;
            readLock.notify();
        }
    }

    public Response send(Command command, int responseTimeout) throws TimeOutException {
        Packet packet = new Packet();
        packet.setCommand(command.getCommandCode());
        packet.setData(command.getCommandData());
        packet.setAddress(deviceAddress);

        synchronized (readLock) {
            responsePacket = null;
            channelFuture.channel().writeAndFlush(packet).syncUninterruptibly();
            try {
                readLock.wait(responseTimeout);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            if (responsePacket == null)
                throw new TimeOutException();
            return Response.get(responsePacket);
        }
    }
}
```

On the decoder, it aways comes with 0 readableBytes and I not sure the enconder is sending any data at all. My only guess is that the server needs to be a Netty implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does a Netty client work with a netty server only?

No.  In general Netty provides networking abstractions and event-loop constructs to alleviate the pains and pitfalls of rolling your own.

Although your example is relatively simple I would recommend structuring your code off of a working example and then add features/structure once the pieces make more sense.  For example check out the [echo examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo). Try using this structure and don't worry about getting a clean class hierarchy (synchronization, timeouts, etc..) until you can send/receive some bytes.

Also in general be careful when you are using the `ByteBuf` interface.  Your `input.getByte(..)` calls are using absolute indexing which is not based on the `readerIndex()` which may lead to out of bounds exceptions.  Please refer to the [ByteBuf javadocs](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html) but you may just want to stick with `readByte()` or at least use `readerIndex()`.

Some other general troubleshooting questions:

1) Have you verified that you are sending correct information and the device is receiving it?

2) Have you verified the device is responding with the anticipated response?

Comment: I wrote a test using sockets and the device is working as expected. I think the netty implementation is not sending the data at all and I can't find the reason.

Comment: How are you making sure the channel is actually connected?  The `channelFuture = b.connect(address, port);` operation is asynchronous.  Try putting a `.sync()` on the end of that call.